# how to come out of prompt loop?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am stuck in a situation where if user is not entering correct/expected data for a required parameter it is constantly re-prompting the user to enter the data.

Is it possible to break the conversation after few prompts?

> Example:
>   Bot  - what size of coffee do you want? (available answers are small, med, large)
>   User - big
>   Bot  - what size of coffee do you want?
>   User - bigger Bot  - what size of coffee do you want?
>   User - bigggggg Bot  - what size of coffee do you want?
>   ...

There was similar functionality available in amazon-lex.

[image]

Comment: If you can share a bit of your code I might be able to help

Comment: @ChukaOkoye the code will not execute at this point. i have posted amazon-lex's functionality pic as well for clarification.

Comment: do not compare lex with dialogflow both are different platform.

Comment: @AbhinavTyagi i know both are different, i just wrote that so that it would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when the intent is not identified either because of lifespan expiration or no proper training.
Use a flag to keep a track to such prompts.

- use default fallback or intent's fallback intent.
- in the webhook, set the "unknownPrompt" flag in the parameters.
- when the count reaches 3, exit the conversation.
- when the correct intent is triggered (any intent), in the webhook, reset the "unknownPrompt" to 0.

**UPDATE**
This is not Amazon-Lex, it's Dialogflow which is a different platform. Do not compare the features as they are owned by different organizations. Not everything would be same.
You may additionally check out following best practices.

- [Dialogflow General](https://dialogflow.com/docs/best-practices/agent-design)
- [Action on Google](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/best-practices)

Comment: but the webhook code will only execute after it gets all the parameters/entities. i have updated question as well.

Comment: from your question it looks, it is not collecting parameters and you cannot ask the question forever. Enable webhook for slot filing and handle it in the webhook.